# Why are we returning the head of the TreeNode after each recursive call?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a question regarding the trace of the following recursive solution: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/solution/

It is simply to `merge two sorted linked list`.

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        if l1 is None:
            return l2
        elif l2 is None:
            return l1
        elif l1.val < l2.val:
            l1.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
            return l1
        else:
            l2.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
            return l2
```

Generally, I can follow recursive solutions through, but with ListNodes I am struggling to understand how one connects to another at each recursive call. In particular, why are we returning `l1` and `l2` after each recursive call? Is this to ensure that we maintain and return the head of the linked list at the end of the function?

I do understand the premise of the solution, which is to compare the heads of the two link lists and connect it with the remainder of the linked list at each stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why are we returning l1 and l2 after each recursive call?

First of all, the goal of the function is to return a list, so at least *something* needs to be returned, in all cases.

> I do understand the premise of the solution, which is to compare the heads of the two link lists and connect it with the remainder of the linked list at each stage.

This comparison decides which node will be the head of the list to be returned, so already when we find that `l1.val < l2.val`, it is clear that `l1` must be the head node of the returned list, and so it is expected there will be a `return l1`.

The recursive call shifts the problem to a situation where the `l1` node is not included any more: we already know that `l1` will be first, so the problem is *reduced* by not considering it any more, and solving that smaller problem through recursion. The recursive call will return a list whose first node will be the node that we have to put right *after* `l1`. So that is why the recursive result is assigned to `l1.next`. Note how important it is that the recursive call returns a list (node)!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Trincot, one question though- you mention that if l1.val<l2.val then clearly l1 must be the head node of the returned list (I completely agree), however I don't quite understand in the recursive sense when something is 'returned'.

Comment: For say iterative solutions, we 'return' the final solution, but here it is clearly not the case. So when we say 'return' what is it exactly that we mean? I know that in some cases, when we 'return' it calls the next recursive function in the recursion stack

Comment: When you return, you backtrack: the call stack becomes smaller. In this case, the returned value is the solution for the smaller problem that was given to the recursive call. It comes back (by a `return` that it performs itself) with the solution for *that* problem. We add to that what is needed to solve the *current* (larger) problem -- which in this case means that we *prefix* a node to that smaller solution, and then we need to pass that back to the guy that called us -- so we must `return` the solution.

Comment: The principle with a function call is often like this: the caller provides input for it via arguments, and the function *returns* the output for it. You give input, and get output in return. In this case you give it two lists, and you get returned from it a merged list. That merged list only relates to the lists that were given to the function. We call the recursive function always with one node less, so then we will also get back a solution that does not have that removed node. Each recursive call solves a smaller problem.

Comment: Another confusion may arise when one wrongly assumes that the `l1` and `l2` variables are *common* to all execution contexts of the recursive function. They are not. Each recursive execution context has its own set of variables. When the caller calls with `mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)`, then the recursive context will *receive* those references and name them `l1` and `l2`. For `l2` there is no confusion, but in this case the caller's `l1.next` is equal to the callee's `l1`. The latter is a local name used by the callee. The caller still has its own, different `l1` reference.

Answer (score 0):

More or less, the process here goes as such:

When you use next, you get the next value of the iterator, by returning the variables (`l1`/`l2`) you keep that position.

Initially, since the lists are sorted, if you compare between the top items (`l1.val`,`l2.val`) you can get the higher value, and extracting the lower one (this output seems to be ascending), you can repeat the process as every time you use next, the value changes.

Returning `L1` after next ensures that we do not have repeated values from `L1`, and reducing the complexity of needing to mess around with indexes and what-not

Eventually, one of the lists will be empty (the first two conditions) and all of the remaining values will be added there.

Comment: Thanks Zaid, one question, for the base case above- if L2 becomes empty first, we will return L1 correct? However let's say that in the list L2, the first element is smaller than the first element of L1- wouldn't this lead to a wrong output?

Comment: Since we need to return L2 instead of L1

Comment: It is recursive, so l1 parts were returned already, so it's building on top of it.